# Having a scrolling issue where if I scroll the full page, it disables scroll for list view and sliding up panel

Tags: android, flutter, dart, scroll

I'm currently working on this page, I have attached a photo of it below. I'm having an issue where if I scroll on the full page (out of the list view) it disables scroll for the listview and for the sliding up panel. So for instance if there are only two workouts listed, and i scroll beneath the listview, i can no longer slide up the "SlidingUpPanel" unless I tap on it first. When I have as many workouts as shown in the picture below, if I scroll on the sides of the listview, and then try to scroll the listview or slide up the sliding up panel, it also does not work. Would appreciate some help with this, have experimented with physics, controllers, and cannot figure it out.

[image]

```
class Workouts extends StatefulWidget {
  const Workouts({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Workouts> createState() => _WorkoutsState();
}

class _WorkoutsState extends State<Workouts> {
  Future<List<Workout>>? futureWorkouts;
  final workoutDB = WorkoutListDB();
  final upperScrollController = ScrollController();
  final lowerScrollController = ScrollController();
  final panelScrollController = ScrollController();
  Workout? selectedWorkout;

  void revertToCreateWorkout() {
    setState(() {
      selectedWorkout = null;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchWorkouts();
  }

  void fetchWorkouts() {
    setState(() {
      futureWorkouts = workoutDB.fetchAll();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefBackground(
      body: EliteScaffold(
        stretch: false,
        appBar: SuperAppBar(
          actions: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                selectedWorkout = null;
                });
              },
            icon: const Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.white),
          ),
          leading: const DefBackButton(),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          previousPageTitle: "",
          title: Text(
            "Workouts",
            style: TextStyle(color: context.theme.appColors.onSurface),
          ),
          searchBar: SuperSearchBar(
            enabled: false,
          ),
          largeTitle: SuperLargeTitle(
            enabled: true,
            largeTitle: "Workouts",
            height: 45,
          ),
        ),
        body: SafeArea(
          top: false,
          bottom: false,
          child: SlidingUpPanel(
            minHeight: 185,
            maxHeight: 750,
            snapPoint: 0.5,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
              topRight: Radius.circular(15),
            ),
            panel: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                topRight: Radius.circular(15),
              ),
              child: selectedWorkout != null
                  ? WorkoutDetails(workout: selectedWorkout!, onDonePressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  selectedWorkout = null;
                });
              })
                  : CreateWorkoutTwo(controller: lowerScrollController),
            ),
            body: Stack(
              children: [
                Listener(
                  onPointerMove: (event) {
                    if (event.delta.dy < 0) {
                      // Only forward the scroll events to the SlidingUpPanel when scrolling upwards
                      panelScrollController.animateTo(panelScrollController.offset + event.delta.dy, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0), curve: Curves.linear);
                    }
                  },
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0, left: 15.0, right: 15.0, bottom: 200),
                    child: SlidableAutoCloseBehavior(
                      closeWhenTapped: true,
                      closeWhenOpened: true,
                      child: Container(
                        height: 550,
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                          child: FutureBuilder<List<Workout>>(
                            future: futureWorkouts,
                            builder: (context, snapshot) {
                              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                              } else if (snapshot.hasError || snapshot.data == null) {
                                return const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Error loading workouts.',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 28,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
                              } else {
                                final workouts = snapshot.data!;

                                return workouts.isEmpty
                                    ? const Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    'No Workouts...',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      fontSize: 28,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                )
                                    : NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                                  onNotification: (notification) {
                                    if (notification is ScrollUpdateNotification) {
                                      if (notification.metrics.pixels < 0) {
                                        panelScrollController.animateTo(
                                            panelScrollController.offset + notification.scrollDelta!,
                                            duration: Duration(milliseconds: 0),
                                            curve: Curves.linear
                                        );
                                      }
                                    }
                                    return false; // Allow event to propagate further
                                  },
                                    child: ListView.separated(
                                      controller: upperScrollController,
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
                                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(
                                      height: 0,
                                      thickness: 0.75,
                                      color: context.theme.appColors.tertiaryContainer,
                                                                        ),
                                                                        itemCount: workouts.length,
                                                                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                      final workout = workouts[index];

                                      return ClipRRect(
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                          topLeft: index == 0 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                          topRight: index == 0 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                          bottomLeft:
                                          index == workouts.length - 1 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                          bottomRight:
                                          index == workouts.length - 1 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                        ),
                                        child: DefBlur(
                                          child: Container(
                                            color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                            child: Slidable(
                                              endActionPane: ActionPane(
                                                extentRatio: 0.25,
                                                motion: const DrawerMotion(),
                                                children: [
                                                  SlidableAction(
                                                    onPressed: (context) async {
                                                      await workoutDB.delete(workout.id);
                                                      fetchWorkouts();
                                                    },
                                                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                                                    icon: Icons.delete,
                                                  )
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                              child: ListTile(
                                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                                    topLeft: index == 0 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                                    topRight: index == 0 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                                    bottomLeft:
                                                    index == workouts.length - 1 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                                    bottomRight:
                                                    index == workouts.length - 1 ? const Radius.circular(12) : Radius.zero,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                title: Text(
                                                  workout.name,
                                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                subtitle: Text(
                                                  workout.description ?? '',
                                                  style: TextStyle(color: context.theme.appColors.onSurface),
                                                ),
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  setState(() {
                                                    selectedWorkout = workout;
                                                  });
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      );
                                                                        },
                                                                      ),
                                    );
                              }
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a simplified version of your code?